# Is there a significant difference between these two linq methods?

Tags: performance, linq, query-optimization

We have some repo methods, and I see a lot of our team using our GetAll() method over another (Get()):

Example use case:

```
 var user = _uow.UserRepository.GetAll().Include(x => x.UserMap).Include(x=>x.UserFile).Include(x=>x.UserDomains).FirstOrDefault(x => emails.Contains(x.Email));
```

I'm wondering if instead they be using this one?

```
var user = _uow.UserRepository.Get(x => emails.Contains(x.Email), "UserMap,UserFile,UserDomains");
```

Here are those two methods:

```
public virtual TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, string includeTables = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _entities;

            if (filter != null)
                query = query.Where(filter);

            foreach (var includeTable in includeTables.Split(new char[] { ',' },
              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeTable);
            }

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

```
        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _entities.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Is the Get() method more efficient than the GetAll() method? In my mind, the GetAll() method is calling everything in the table (we're using a Repository pattern with one repository per table), then narrowing down afterward, whereas the Get() is being more specific.

Can anyone tell me if my intuition is right or wrong about this? I'm wondering how efficient that GetAll() is given the use-case.

Comment: `Get` will be slower in milliseconds.  If you can, remove  repository pattern and improve speed and maintainability.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Ok, thank you for the advice; I am not sure how much performance/efficiency was in mind when these things were initially implemented. Repository = not good anymore. Is Unit of Work still good? Might be for another question/extra research...

Comment: If GetAll was using AsEnumerable() then it would be calling everything in the table and filtering afterwards, but as it is using AsQueryable(), that should not apply. I would prefer GetAll() as the Get() method uses a string to contain the names of the tables to be included, so you don't get any compile time validation.

Comment: @Trevor, DbSet  is already generic repository, DbContext is already UoW. Additional abstractions are useless. If you need unit testing, just point DbContext to in-memory SQLite.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Haha it makes sense that we would be making additional abstractions... Thank you very much!